# Python Multiprocessing with Frame

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Currently working on a project that requires multi threading to interact with a physical device while having an active frame open to send instructions.

The problem is that when the Frame is spawned and the "Hello" button is pressed, the `test` method is ran and the `Process` running `LEDBehavior.BlinkYellowLightEverySecond ()` is properly being ran, but the button remains in it's pressed graphical state and the window becomes unresponsive.

Here is the code for this frame.

```
import LEDBehavior

class MainFrame (Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets ()

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.hi_there = Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello",
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.test

        self.hi_there.pack({"side": "left"})

    def test (self):

        p1 = Process (LEDBehavior.BlinkYellowLightEverySecond ())
        p1.start ()
        p1.join ()

# create the application
myapp = MainFrame ()

#
# here are method calls to the window manager class
#
myapp.master.title ("Sample Text inc, Security Software Professionals")
myapp.master.maxsize (1920, 1080)
myapp.master.minsize (800, 640)

# start the program
myapp.mainloop ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of:

```
p1.join()
```

You're telling your main process to wait on p1. `BlinkYellowLightEverySecond` seems like the type of function that may run forever until stopped, and I'm guessing you don't want to halt your program for this. Just remove the `join` and add a button for stopping/changing the blink.

**EDIT**

Second error I missed:

```
p1 = Process (LEDBehavior.BlinkYellowLightEverySecond ())
```

the tuple () after Blink... actually makes the call, so your invoking the function in your main process! Remove the (), and invoke the constructor properly:

```
p1 = Process (target = LEDBehavior.BlinkYellowLightEverySecond)
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.

Comment: I have removed the line `p1.join ()`, yet the problem persist and the Frame remains unresponsive.

Comment: NM, I see the problem - your () after LEDBehavior.BlinkYellowLightEverySecond, I'll edit.

Comment: when I remove the parantheses I am met with this exception http://pastebin.com/4bNfKgXg